# Remove undefined elements from a typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have created a javascript class so it can be reused in the project.

However, not all attributes are being set in the class at a given time.

For example, this is the interface of the `address` class

```
interface Address {
  use: Code,
  type: Code,
  text: string,
  city: string,
  district: string,
  state: string,
  postalCode: string,
  country: string,
  period: Period,
  value?: string | null,
}

class Address {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

If you see the interface, you see that `use` has a type of `Code` which is another type of a class which has method called `get()` which will return a value or an Object

The `Address` class has a `getObject` property which will create an `object` which can later be `strigified` by using `JSON.strigify()`

Here is how I'm going to set the values of an object created by this class,

```
  const address = new Address()
  address.city = "Brisbane"
  address.country = "AUS"
  address.line.push("400, gStreet")
  address.postalCode = "4000"
  address.state = "QLD"
  address.use = new Code("work")
```

However, when i call `address.getObject()` this will trigger an error because the `use` is not set `undefined` and therefore can't call the method, `get()`.

How can I solve this issue?

Do I have to use something like `lodash` to remove undefined elements within an object before calling `getObject()`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not only will you avoid countless headaches, but you will end up with the cleaner, simpler, smaller, and more idiomatic if you don't use classes to represent data that is serialized.

Comment: How can avoid repetition without using classes?

Comment: Functions and plain old objects. Classes do not provide anything you can't do without them and are just sugar for certain patterns that can have their uses but are a terrible match for serialized data.

Comment: Ex: `const address = { city: "Brisbane", county: "AU", etc.}`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WJR6rW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

I can comment due to StackOverflow:

// so this is a comment
the typescript type system is structural meaning that u can use objects when needed and object ( class instance ) when needed
for example, if u want typescript to help u with types and validations use ( classes, types, and interfaces ) otherwise u can use a plain javascript object as @Aluan Haddad said

U can read more here ( not mine ) [typescript type system](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-typescripts-type-system-a3cdec8e95ae)

Good luck